# CouchDB views and references

Tags: view, couchdb

Not sure if/how it is intended to be done but i am trying to match up all the active document in my database with the author of it:

```
function(doc) {
    if (doc.data.active && doc.data.active == '1') {
        emit(doc.data._account.data.name, doc._id);
    }
}
```

the _account field in the db is a reference to a document with all the information about the author, including a name field but because this is a reference I cannot simply "go down".

I tried to look up the docs but kind of hard to find relevant documentation because reference match up to Reference documentation most of the time.

Comment: I think you're going about this the wrong way...if you want to match the active documents to its author, then you've got to have something of the form `emit(doc._id, doc.author_id)` Then you can `include_docs=true` and get the `author` doc for a given active article...